# Base 64 decode with Python on XAMPP

Tags: python, php, base64

I'm trying to bring on my local server (XAMPP), a script that's working on my VPS server (Linux CentOS7).
On XAMPP, I call the Python script wit PHP, something like:

```
$hotel = array("Name"=>$_POST["NAME"]
                  ,..
                );
$param = escapeshellcmd(base64_encode(json_encode($hotel)));
$result = shell_exec('python C:\xampp\htdocs\bounce.py $param');
$obj = json_decode($result);
```

The Python script is something like:

```
#! /Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe
import sys
import json
import base64
    
content = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
print(json.dumps(content))
```

The returned JSON string is NULL
This is the Apache error:

```
[php:warn] [pid 11176:tid 1884] [client ::1:55182] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "Name" on null in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\hotel_results.php on line 46, referer: http://localhost/
```

Updated Django with no results

Comment: Does the python do more than that in reality? Because there's no reason you couldn't do the same task directly in php quite easily

Comment: Are you 100% sure that Python is on the PATH for the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is caused by not reading the "$param" variable due to single quotes, replacing the line of

```
$result = shell_exec('python C:\xampp\htdocs\bounce.py $param');
```

with

```
$result = shell_exec("python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bounce.py $param");
```

could help. worth a try.